# 365 Days Data points store into Arrays over Monthly-Hourly Basis

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

[image]

I have scanned the data from excel to Arraylist but there is all data included under a single place. I have data defined in the above image up to 31st December for every day over the period 7:30 & 8:30. So for each day, there will be 2 rows. hence, 365 days * 2 variable * 8 columns data. And I need to store the data like Month 1 (January) 1st - 31st days of data in different arrays. As I have calculated the mean of 8 columns.

```
try {
            ArrayList<String> GOCIds = new ArrayList<String>();

            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));
            for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
                System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
            }
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
            System.out.println("Excel Data Loading....");
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    String tempValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    GOCIds.add(tempValue);
                }
            }
// allMonth
            for (int i = 0; i < masterData.size(); i = i + 11) {
                allMonth.add(masterData.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Total Month " + allMonth.size());
            // allDay
            for (int i = 1; i < masterData.size(); i = i + 11) {
                allDay.add(masterData.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Total Day " + allDay.size());
            // allTime
            for (int i = 2; i < masterData.size(); i = i + 11) {
                allTime.add(masterData.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Total Time " + allTime.size());
            // allDHI
            for (int i = 3; i < masterData.size(); i = i + 11) {
                allDHI.add(masterData.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Total DHI " + allDHI.size());
            // allDNI
            for (int i = 4; i < masterData.size(); i = i + 11) {
                allDNI.add(masterData.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Total DNI " + allDNI.size());
            // allGHI
            for (int i = 5; i < masterData.size(); i = i + 11) {
                allGHI.add(masterData.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Total GHI " + allGHI.size());
            // allDEW
            for (int i = 6; i < masterData.size(); i = i + 11) {
                allDEW.add(masterData.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Total DEW " + allDEW.size());
            // allTemperature
            for (int i = 7; i < masterData.size(); i = i + 11) {
                allTemperature.add(masterData.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Total Temperature " + allTemperature.size());
            // allPressure
            for (int i = 8; i < masterData.size(); i = i + 11) {
                allPressure.add(masterData.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Total Pressure " + allPressure.size());
            // allHumidity
            for (int i = 9; i < masterData.size(); i = i + 11) {
                allHumidity.add(masterData.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Total Humidity " + allHumidity.size());
            // allWS
            for (int i = 10; i < masterData.size(); i = i + 11) {
                allWS.add(masterData.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Total WS " + allWS.size());

            System.out.println("Data Loading Done ^_^");
```

Can you please guide how can i load monthly-hourly data in 8 different arrays so that I can calculate the means for each of them easily ?

Comment: I have tried with multidimensional array along with arraylist but not able to store the data month wise in a single place. Can someone help with code ?

Comment: It seems that you should first of all model your data properly and design proper classes and objects to hold them. Also for representation of dates and times look into [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Not sure, but you may have inadvertently applied this [anti-pattern parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/).

Answer (score 1):

I think first of all you have to load all data from excel file to the model.

```
public final class Data {
    private int month;    // [0:11]
    private int day;      // [1:31]
    private long time;
    private int dhi;
    private int dni;
    private int ghi;
    private int dewPoint;
    private double remperature;
    private double pressure;
    private double relativeHumidity;
    private double windSpeed;
}

public static List<Data> readDataFromExcel(Path xlsx) throws Exception {
    try(Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(Files.newInputStream(xlsx))) {
        List<Data> res = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(Row row : workbook.getSheetAt(0)) {
            Data data = new Data();
            
            for(Cell cell : row) {
                // fill data
            }
            
            res.add(data);
        }
        
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then `List<Data>` allows you to calculate results or group by e.g. day etc.